# Automating copying and pasting text on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, notes.app, copy-paste, shortcuts-app

I am cleaning up notes on my iPhone and separating them into distinct notes by cutting certain parts of the text, creating a new note and then pasting it. Is there any option for automating this process. Workflow is:

- I could just highlight some text, press a button
- I would immediately go to a new note and paste the highlighted (and copied) text there.

Would the Shortcuts app help at all with this?

Comment: Yes, Shortcuts could help.  Have you searched the various custom Shortcuts sites (Routine Hub, Reddit, etc)?

Comment: I had never heard of those sites, but those are both quite a catch. Thank you!